# Заполнение переменных класса массивом с идентификатором

Tags: c#

Есть класс только со свойствами

```
class SomeStruct{
   public string Paper_1 { get; set; }
   public string Paper_2 { get; set; }
   public string Paper_3 { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Каким образом можно заполнить переменные этого класса с помощью цикла, по типу:

```
SomeStruct someSt = new SomeStruct();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    someSt[i] = someData[i]
}
```

или

```
foreach (var item in someSt) 
{
    item = someData
}
```

Или как можно обратиться к переменной класса не по имени а по идентификатору?

Comment: Использовать не несколько полей, а простой массив?

Comment: Простой массив не подходит, нужна именно структура с переменными(свойствами), т.к. она используется в работе с базой данных через EntityFramework.
`using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    db.SomeStruct.Add(someSt);
    db.SaveChanges();
}`

Comment: Раз возникла потребность так заполнять данные, значит со структурой БД у вас что-то не так.

Comment: @aepot не обязательно. Всякие бывают случаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"как можно обратиться к переменной класса не по имени а по идентификатору?"

```
someSt.GetType().GetProperty($"Paper_{i}").SetValue(someSt, newvalue);
var result = someSt.GetType().GetProperty($"Paper_{i}").GetValue(someSt);
```

Comment: Стоит только помнить, что рефлексия - это медленно. Если нужна производительность, потребуется ряд оптимизаций.

Answer (score 1):

Если типы всех свойств совпадают, то можно реализовать индексатор:

```
class SomeStruct
{
    public string Paper_1 { get; set; }
    public string Paper_2 { get; set; }
    public string Paper_3 { get; set; }

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return i switch
            {
                0 => Paper_1,
                1 => Paper_2,
                2 => Paper_3,
            };
        }
        set
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: Paper_1 = value; break;
                case 1: Paper_2 = value; break;
                case 2: Paper_3 = value; break;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

И добавить свойство `Count`, которое будет возвращать количество свойств `Paper_X` в данном классе

Если свойств очень много, но их имена соответствуют паттерну `Paper_X`, то можно использовать рефлексию совместно с индексатором:

```
public string this[int i]
{
    get => PapersProperties[i].GetValue(this).ToString();
    set => PapersProperties[i].SetValue(this, value);
}

Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo> papersProperties;
Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo> PapersProperties => papersProperties ??= GetPapersInfo();

public Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo> GetPapersInfo()
{
    var papersProperties = new Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo>();
    var papers = typeof(SomeStruct).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Paper_"));
    foreach (var paper in papers)
    {
        int key = Convert.ToInt32(paper.Name.Substring(6,1)) - 1;
        papersProperties.Add(key, paper);
    }
    return papersProperties;
}
```